# Angular - importing and using a custom module - getting StaticInjector error

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular7

I have an Angular 7 project with a multi-project folder structure. I've created a module for each project. For this example, let's assume I have two projects, a main and sub.

My main-project.module.ts:

```
//main-project.module.ts
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MainProjectComponent } from './main-project.component';
import { SubProjectModule } from '../../../sub-project/src/app/sub-project.module';
import { routing } from './main-project-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MainProjectComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    routing,
    SubProjectModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [MainProjectComponent]
})
export class MainProjectModule { }
```

My sub-project.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { routing } from "./sub-project-routes.routes";
import { StatusComponent } from "./components/status.component";
import { SubProjectService } from "./services/sub-project.service";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    SubProjectComponent,
    StatusComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    routing,
  ],
  providers: [SubProjectService],
  bootstrap: [SubProjectComponent]
})
export class SubProjectModule { }
```

From my understanding, if I import the SubProjectModule in MainProjectModule, I shouldn't have to add services or components that are uses specifically by the SubProject in the MainProject module file - is this correct?

Right now, if I try to create the SubProjectComponent (which uses the StatusComponent declared in the declarations section of SubProjectModule), I get the following error:

```
StaticInjectorError(MainProjectModule)[StatusComponent -> SubProjectComponent]: No provider for SubProjectComponent!
```

Here is my SubProjectComponent template:

```
<h2>This is the SubProjectComponent page.</h2>
<status></status> <!--'status' is the html selector for the StatusComponent-->
```

I recently upgraded an old Angular 2 project to Angular 7 so restructuring hasn't been too smooth. What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: you want to be able to use the SubProjectComponent in the MainProjectModule components right?

Comment: You can't use a SubProjectComponent inside the template of a component declared in MainProjectModule. It's only usable inside other components of SubProjectModule, unless it's exported by the module. If that's not the issue, please provide a complete minimal reproduction of your issue in a Stackblitz.

Comment: How does your `SubProjectService` look like? Is it created as a singleton? Have you tried using angular recommended way to create a singleton service via `providedIn: 'root'`?

Comment: @MichaelAshefor Yes - I know I can import SubProjectComponent directly inside the MainProjectModule, but I thought importing the SubProjectModule would suffice since SubProjectComponent is imported there. The full SubProjectModule is much more complex and contains a lot more import statements which is why I wanted to just import SubProjectModule into MainProjectModule.

Comment: Sorry, I read it wrong thought you were having issues with services, but instead you want to use the components inside your `SubProjectComponent` in order to do that you would need to `export` those component in your `SubProjectModule`, similarly how you did with `declarations`

Comment: @penleychan That fixed my issue - thanks! If you remake your post as an answer instead of a comment I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use components from `SubProjectModule` you would need to `export` those components.

```
@NgModule({
   declarations: [
      SubProjectComponent,
      StatusComponent
   ],
   imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      routing,
   ],
   exports: [
      SubProjectComponent,
      StatusComponent
   ],
   providers: [SubProjectService],
   bootstrap: [SubProjectComponent]
})
export class SubProjectModule { }
```